# find element that has certain class and then select it

Tags: jquery

the element can change according to users' action, that's why I use on()

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click','li', function(){
  if($('li').hasClass()){

    //do something <-- but it return true (boolean)
  }

});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ see this

Comment: Just so you know, `.on()` can be used as a delegate (as you're implying here, e.g. `.on(eventtype, selector, callback)`), and as a standard event handler (like `.bind()`, e.g. `.on(eventtype, callback)`). So *"that's why I use `on()`"* doesn't really hold much water.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
$(document).on('click','li.yourclass', function(){

    //do something with your element, which is "this"

});
```

The `'li.yourclass'` selector is dynamically tested at each click, so you don't need to test in the callback.

Comment: @tempali yes, it's totally dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click','li', function(){
  if(if ($('li').hasClass('yourclassname'))){

    //do something <-- but it return true (boolean)
  }
});
```

Comment: class is not attribute its property so i think prop is best

Comment: and there's a `hasClass` function anyway.